# Arduino Nano I2C OLED display 0.96 inches 128x64 pixels

Tags: arduino-nano, oled

I have a strange issue while trying to run the hello world code on an arduino nano connected to an OLED display.

This is the code I used:

```
    #include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
Adafruit_SSD1306 display = Adafruit_SSD1306(128, 64, &Wire);

void setup() {

  // SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC = generate display voltage from 3.3V internally
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); // Address 0x3C for 128x32

  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  display.clearDisplay();      //this line to clear previous logo
  display.setTextColor(WHITE); //without this no display
  display.print("Hello World!");//your TEXT here
  display.display();            //to shows or update your TEXT
}

void loop() {

 }
```

But I get this on the display.
[image: OLED]

[image]

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the product link of your display?

Comment: I had this display laying around for a while, unfortunately I can't find the product link.

Comment: Is the driver IC SSD1306? Can you see that at the back of the display?

Comment: Not sure where can I see that, I added a picture with the back.

Comment: Why are you using Adafruit_SSD1306 library? It is possible that the display driver is not SSD1306. Also, from your second picture, it looks like the address is `0x78`. In the code, you are using `0x3C`. Also, show us how did you connect the display with Arduino Nano.

Comment: Also, check if the display I2C pins have pull-ups.

Comment: @Fahad This doesn't look like an I2C problem, but rather something with the font handling (note that the "H" and "W" are correct, but the rest of the letters are somewhat off (L=E, S=L, etc.) I'd try reinstalling the library.

Comment: Good point. I have seen other people said sometimes Chinese manufactured display have the address `0x7A` but works with `0x3C`. But the pull-up can be a problem. If there is no pull-up, the floating state can generate `garbage` data.

Comment: 0x7A is 0x3C << 1 which is correct. I2C addresses are 7 bits and the 8th bit (rightmost) is use as a R/W flag. So you shift the I2C address one to the left and then add a 1 or 0 to the left for read/write operation (I forget which way around it is). The Arduino library does that for you, so you need to provide the "unshifted" address of 0x3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved :)

After some more reading it appears that the display driver is actually SH1106, so after using the [right](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SH110x) library I got the display working.[image]